# Javascript : doesn't support property or method 'hasAttribute'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a JavaScript error displaying when I use a web application (doesn't support property or method `hasAttribute`) on IE.

Doing the research it seems to be IE version related.

The problem is that it works perfectly on my colleague's computers with the same IE version.

What are the differences which can influence JavaScript execution that I can compare?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_hasattribute.asp

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) We can't help you with code we can't see. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: hasAttribute is not supported on IE8 or older versions. The other explanation (if you are using IE9 or newer) is that the DOM element couldn't be selected in your case (but it could for some reason on your friend's computer).

Comment: Which IE versions are used? Check the browser support section in the link provided by Juan Elfers

Comment: It's also possible that even with IE9-11, IE is running in the massively-misnamed "compatibility mode" for you (pretending it's IE8 or IE7) while not running in "compatibility mode" for your colleagues.

Comment: I use eclipse version 11. None of you understand my question except T.J. Crowder. This is not a version related problem. Indeed my colleagues have exactly the same IE version but not the same problem.We also have the same compatible mode. I run it from local tomcat in eclipse so i suspect maybe a tomcat parameter